# How does a relational database organize data?

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures, relational-database, hashtable

I was thinking that a relational database will store every possible query and the values to return for that query in a hash table.

So like, if each entry in your table had 5 attributes, then you would make a copy of that element for each subset of the 5 attributes that appear in any given query that should return that specific entry. So every individual entry would appear 2^5 = 32 times in the table. This seems like it would be very memory inefficient for large data sets with many entries, but it also allows for the fastest possible query time.

Do real world relational-databases have a mixed version of this where some response time for queries/lookups is traded off for more memory efficiency? If so, how would this be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how relational databases store data. Keep in mind it's a lot more than 2^32, because you can make queries that have expressions, not simply references to attribute columns. Also queries that are joins, which expands the possibilities immensely.

Even if you could store all possible combinations, it would be a waste because most of them will never be needed.

Instead, databases typically store records, where a record includes all columns of one table. If you run a query that only needs some columns, the DBMS still fetches the whole record, and simply ignores columns that you didn't ask for. Then it evaluates any expressions in your query. And finally returns the result set.

MySQL does not use hash tables to store these records, it uses a B+Tree data structure, so looking up a record by its primary key takes O(log n) time.

Comment: Hmm. _Some_ DBMSs store your data as records ('horizontally') -- typically those optimised for high transaction rates (updates). Some store as indexes ('vertically') https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS -- typically those optimised for retrieval such as a data warehouse. If one table (more likely several) has a FK to another, store both the referred-to and the referencing columns in the same index.

Comment: True. Column-oriented DBMS is another type of animal. But I don't know of any that do what the OP described, storing every possible result. The MySQL Query Cache is the closest thing to that, but it only stores temporary copies of results from queries you have run, not every possible query.